# ArcGIS Server directory use to store intermediate files

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, python-toolbox

I have a tool which does the following work:

1. Connects and fetches data from hdf using impala
2. Create intermediate csv file.
3. from the csv file it creates custom feature classes.

Currently when running it as a standalone tool I have used absolute paths in the local disks and it works fine. I have used random number to generate different work directories to store the data.

Now I need to publish this tool as a geoprocessing service. So I need to access the server directories to save my intermediate files.

As I read, each time a tool is run it creates a folder with a unique id within arcgisjob folder. If I understood right, I need access to that directory.

Please suggest how to use the folder.

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 Server for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [arcpy.env.scratchFolder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000046000000) to handle intermediate files.  The ArcGIS help state:

> Its primary purpose is for use by scripts and models as geoprocessing services, with the added focus of pointing only to a known folder. When ArcGIS for Server executes a geoprocessing task, the Scratch Folder is always available to write output to.

[Scratch Folder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000046000000) is available since ArcGIS 10.1.  Prior to 10.1 must use [Scratch Workspace](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Scratch_Workspace/001w00000003000000/) instead, which has the drawback of not distinguishing if the scratch environment is a folder or a geodatabase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.My question remains as how do I point the scratch workspace as the current job folder within the arcgis server.I have tried setting the scratch folder but when i run it as geoprocessing service it is not creating the intermediate files in the arcjobs folder.

Comment: @ArijitBose In the linked documentation: `arcpy.env.scratchFolder`. That contains a file path. You use it like you would any other file path in Python.

Comment: @ArijitBose could you please paste your script?  It might be easier to identify the problem.